# Get Value from Javascript File

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have created one javascript file(.js) for Language Settings. So how can I get values from this file.?

File.

```
{
"language" : "german",

"glossary" : {
    "Level" : "Ebene",
    "Codes" : "Codes",
} }
```

So how to set value to particular label.?

I want "Ebene" instead of "Level".
For Eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById("lblLevel").innerHTML = glossary["Level"];
```

```
<div class="level">
     <b id = "lblLevel">Level</b>
</div>
```

But Its not working.
Any Idea..?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Also import javascript file :  <script src="scripts/German_Words.js"></script>

Comment: Did you check the answer I have given.

Comment: did you check the answer of @pKs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var language = {
        "language": "german",
        "glossary": {
            "Level": "Ebene",
            "Codes": "Codes"
        }
    };

function ab()
{
document.getElementById("lblLevel").innerHTML = language.glossary.Level;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="ab()">
<div class="level">
     <b id ="lblLevel">Level</b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**@Manan This is working and tested code. Try it. If you have any other issue then comment else up vote the answer and close the question.**

Comment: Yea. Its working.
But we have to write script file in same html page. Its can't getting values from .js file. So any solution.?

Comment: What is the event on which you want to do this thing?

Comment: I want to display labels after getting response. All key/pair values are stored in different .js file. I want values from that file.

Answer (score 5):

In your `language.js` file:

```
var language = {
    "language": "german",
    "glossary": {
        "Level": "Ebene",
        "Codes": "Codes"
    }
};
```

Then in your HTML file:

```
document.getElementById("lblLevel").innerHTML = language.glossary.Level;
```

Comment: Thanks man for answer. Still its not working. I don't know..:(

Comment: Well in that case you need to do some debugging. Check that the DOM object exists when you're running your JS (it might not yet at that point; you might need to delay it with an OnDomReady or something). Check that the language object exists, and that `language.glossary.Level` exists. Basically trace it through each step there.

Comment: Yea. Its working.
But we have to write script file in same html page. Its can't getting values from .js file. So any solution.?

Comment: It doesn't work if there's a `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/language.js"></script>` in the `<head>`?